# How can I import the "communication style" field when importing contacts?

Tags: contacts, import, fields

In my csv I have a field named "Communication style", which I wish to map to the respective field in "communication preferences" for each contact in CiviCRM (formal / familiar).

Yet, while importing the constituents, on the "match fields" step 2, I don't see the "communication style" option in the drop-down.

Which is the way to do this matching?

Answer (score 1):

From [communication_style_id not fully supported](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20214?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) in issues.civicrm.org:

> Unfortunately, support for this field is not completed: We can enter it,
>   export it and search after it using the search builder, and use it within
>   profiles.
>   However, it also should be implemented for:
>
> > - Importing of contacts
> > - Advanced Search